# How to synchronize an intermediate model that has several types?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have table of Practices (`practices`):

### | id |       title       |

1  |  Php              |
  2  |  Database         |
  3  |  JavaScript       |

And related table (`practice_user`):

### | user_id | practice_id |     type    |

```
 1    |      1      |  expertise  |
 1    |      2      |  expertise  |
 1    |      5      |  expertise  |
 1    |      4      |  request    |
 1    |      3      |  request    |
```

Model User:

```
    /**
     * Get the expertise for the User.
     *
     */
    public function expertise()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Practice::class)->where('type', 'expertise');
    }
```

Then try to sync only type where = expertise

```
$user->expertise()->sync($request->practices);
```

But Type where = request entries are also deleted. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `wherePivot` method instead of `where`.

(I don't understand how your code doesn't break because of the `where` method.)